# How to Split the address string, House number and Street Name using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to separate the house number and street name from an address.

I'm able to split most of the addresses until I get to an address that contains Numbers and letters as part of the HouseNumber.

I have tried below and it works for most part. But it doesn't work for an address like *876A Mountain Breeze Rd.* I'm unable to split the House Number **876A** from rest of the address.

Is their a way to split the **876A** As the [House Number]?

```
SELECT
   C.CustomerID
   ,CASE
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress), CHARINDEX(' ', 
LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)))) = 1 THEN
           LEFT(LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress), CHARINDEX(' ', 
LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)))
       ELSE
           NULL
   END AS [House Number]

 ,CASE
       WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress), CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)))) = 1 THEN
           LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(
                                    LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress),
                                    CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)) + 1,
                                    LEN(LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)))))
       ELSE
           LTRIM(RTRIM(C.ServiceAddress))
   END AS [Street Name]
 FROM dbo.Customers AS C
```

Comment: For the house number is it always going to be the first string before the space?  So will the house number regardless of if it is numbers or letters be combined into 1 string only and then the start of the rest is the space?  So you can just parse the data to the first space?

Comment: @Brad -- Yes the house number regardless of if it is numbers or letters be combined into 1 string only and then the start of the rest is the space. The addresses like "26600 SW 146th Ct" my script works fine. Only when its like "876A Mountain Breeze Rd" my code doesn't work. Its unable to split the "876A"

Comment: `ISNUMERIC`, `LTRIM`, `LEFT`, `CHARINDEX` are all database built-in functions and not part of standard SQL, i.e. they are database specific. I'm guessing Microsoft SQL Server. Am I correct? In any case you should add a tag to your question indicating which DBMS you are using.

Comment: @Abra yes Microsoft Sql Server

Comment: it is a very complex question. there are some 3rd party packages that do it like Task Factory for SSIS. https://www.sentryone.com/products/task-factory/feature/ssis-address-parse-transform

Comment: How do you handle "42 1/2 N. South St."? ([Ref](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28ape_004.htm).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and see if its giving you correct results?

```
SELECT
C.CustomerID
,CASE
   WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress), CHARINDEX(' ', 
LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)))) = 1 OR ISNUMERIC(LEFT(LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress), CHARINDEX(' 
', 
LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)))) = 0 THEN
       LEFT(LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress), CHARINDEX(' ', 
LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)))
   ELSE
       NULL
END AS [House Number]

,CASE
   WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress), CHARINDEX(' ', 
LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)))) = 1 OR ISNUMERIC(LEFT(LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress), CHARINDEX(' 
', LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)))) = 0 THEN
       LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(
                                LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress),
                                CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)) + 1,
                                LEN(LTRIM(C.ServiceAddress)))))
   ELSE
       LTRIM(RTRIM(C.ServiceAddress))
 END AS [Street Name]
FROM dbo.Customers AS C
```

Comment: Not working for street names with blanks.